# RDBMS Ingestion task for Apache Druid

Tags: java, druid

I am starting to play with Apache Druid and was wondering if it has the ability to ingest data from an existing RDBMS (Oracle or Postgres)?

**Use Case:**
Currently there multiple sources of data:

- Kafka Streams (Stream real-time data that eventually is inserted into the Relation DB)
- Oracle/Postgres (Historical Data up to 2 Years Old)
- CSV Files (Archived Historical Data 2+ Years Old)

I was hoping to use Apache Druid to abstract the complexities of determining which data source to query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debezium is your solution, it can stream changes from mysql postgres oracle etc and you can send it to Apache druid,

as you already have Kafka it is best solution for your use case,